# Committing front-end libraries to git - good practices

Tags: git, laravel, directory-structure

I bought popular theme from ThemeForest and I want to use it laravel project. I imported it and it works, but I'm not sure how I'm suppose to handle version control and overall structure.

The whole theme with libraries is about ~200MB and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to just put it in public folder, try to make it work in resources, should I import all JS libraries or only those I use or even if should I commit it to git or make some subrepository and commit there.

What are some good practices to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Don't commit frontend libraries.Instead you can use **Bower** and only commit the bower.json file and you can do a bower install on your server.

PS- all this is only possible if you have a dedicated hosting.

Comment: That's what I thought, but there one problem - a lot of included libraries are heavily customized to match the theme, so I can't just download it from somewhere else.

Comment: @ZbigniewKisły you shouldn't edit the source files of those libraries. Instead overwrite them by extending.

Comment: No, I didn't edit them. Authors of the theme did and that's why they don't provide the bower support.

Answer (score 0):

Don't commit frontend libraries. I adding libraries to `.gitignore` or just using **Bower** and only commit the bower.json file.